# access to android application data on application database

Tags: android

I had a application that gathered data and send those data to server.
obviouly once the data has been sent the app will not try to resend it. but recently I found a bug that some data has not been sent to server and once i tried to update my app it said that you should do it with your previous signature  wich i lost it already (I have changed my IDE and SDK and my previous signature has been lost). now I want to know if

is there any way to **update the application with new signature**?

or at least is there any way to **access to application database** and exteract data and **resend it to server**?

how can I **access database file** and **copy it to my PC** and resend its data? (as I have phisycal access to all devices that was using the application)

Comment: please share your database handler code..

Comment: You would need to root the phones and access the DB on physical storage.

Comment: ok but is it plain or encrypted? if it is encrypted how can i decrypt it?

Comment: It depends if you encrypted the database or not, if you did use the same method to decrypt.

Comment: no i just stored data. nothing more for encryption. thank you for your response. and what is is the easiest way to root android devices?

Comment: You said you lost your _previous signature_ because you _changed IDE and SDK_. How did you installed the apps on the devices? Generated an APK or installed a debuggable version?

Comment: i have installed apk. it is not possible to access database of apk?

Comment: If the apk is debuggable you can get the database through adb.